# How to style <option> of a select list?

Tags: jquery

This is my current list ( I made it short). It is created dynamically with php and MySQL:

```
<select name="id_country" id="id_country" class=" opc-form-control">
    <option value="231">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="244">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="230">Albania</option>
    <option value="38">Algeria</option>
    <option value="39">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="40">Andorra</option>
    <option value="41">Angola</option>
    <option value="42">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="232">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="43">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="44">Argentina</option>
    <option value="45">Armenia</option>
    <option value="46">Aruba</option>
    <option value="24" selected="selected">Australia</option>
    <option value="2">Austria</option>
    <option value="47">Azerbaijan</option>
</select>
```

I want to display after option 3 anything from "Border-bottom", or "hr", or "--------------------"

Well with CSS its not possible, I am sure this can be achived with Jquery, but how?

Comment: 1st: what have you tried so far?? 2nd: what the meaning of *after option 3*

Comment: by now I tried $("#id_country").append('<option disabled="disabled">------</option>');

Comment: but how to add after <option value="230">Albania</option>  ?

Comment: you are rendering it in php, so after the index is == 3, add it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can insert a disabled option after the 3rd option in the list using the following jQuery. You can also do this manually in the HTML if your list of options never changes.

```js
$('#id_country option:nth-child(3)').after('<option disabled="disabled">----</option>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="id_country" id="id_country" class=" opc-form-control">
    <option value="231">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="244">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="230">Albania</option>
    <option value="38">Algeria</option>
    <option value="39">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="40">Andorra</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an option/disabled like

```
<option disabled="disabled">------</option>
```

the other option is to use css, but doesn't work in all browsers